# Password encryption in Java

Tags: java, asp.net, encryption

I am storing the user credentials in a properties file, and use them whenever my java application makes a request to the server, and upon confirmation, the user is redirected to an ASP page. The issue with this approach is, the user credentials are visible in the URL, during the redirection to the ASP page.

How do I encrypt the credentials (at least the password) so that exact information is not displayed in the URL?

Comment: You should try using a `post` request instead of a `get` request

Comment: If your only change is encrypting the credentials, then the encrypted credentials will be in the URL. Since the ASP server will now accept encrypted credentials, all I need to access the ASP server is the encrypted credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MessageDigest` SHA encryption to send the data to server. However you need to make changes to your ASP web application to decrypt the credentials. It is not one way street.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the security aspect in mind, consider implementing ***[Salted Password Hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)***.

Comment: Thanks, Sandeep. Looks like something that is do-able.

Answer (score 0):

For this case sharing login information between different applications, the common solution is to use SSO, for example CAS. User login from java application which will get a valid token from CAS server and you can redirct to ASP page with the token instead of user name and password. Your ASP application needs to configue to use CAS to verify the token.

Comment: This is a classic ASP applicaiton. So, is CAS configurable with a calssic ASP applicaiton ??

Comment: I didn't try CAS with ASP page, but I think it should works, or, you can consider other SSO solution.